# Is possible to skip error in executing of bash command?

Tags: linux, command-line, dns, hosts

I am trying to get list of all hostnames from my DNS server by command:

```
host -l example-domain.com mydns.com
```

However one machine has invalid DNS name, because there are two hyphens in row and I get error:

```
host: 'exa--mple.example-domain.com' is not a legal IDNA2008 name.....
```

In this case executing of this command is interrupted and I don't get complete list. Is there any way how to skip this error, and get complete list? Or maybe some other command? I have also tried dig command, but there is same problem:

```
dig @mydns.com example-domain.com axfr
```

Something like "try/catch" would be fine, but I think it doesn't exist in bash. I have also tried export IDN_DISABLE=1 according to manual of command host. Unfortunately, it doesn't help me, still same error. I am using current version of debian.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is possible to send all occurring errors "to the trash" by using

```
command > /dev/null 2>&1
```

or

```
command &>/dev/null
```

For more detailed information visit e.g. [cyberciti](https://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/how-to-redirect-output-and-errors-to-devnull/) or do a quick google search, then you will probably find more detailed tutorials.

Comment: If I used both of these command I will not get any output.

Answer (score 1):

Commands which are part of the bash syntax, have to be right in a script. But you are speaking about the result of the execution of a program called by this bash script. **$?** is the value returned by the last executed command. You can use it to make decisions in the following part of the bash script. Unfortunately, according to man pages of the **host** and **dig** commands, there is no useful code returned.

You have the general capability to redirect the output of the dig or host commands and to analyze it using commands like **grep** or **awk**. But you are depending on the exact syntax of the output of these programs. This syntax can change in future releases of these programs.

Please note a discrepancy in your question. Your host command is asking about **example-domain.com** and the cited output is related to **exa--mple.com**. Further, it is better to always ask about absolute domain names, i.e. ending with a period.

Answer (score 1):

If you just want to `ignore` the error (disregarding the `$?` value), how about using...

```
somecommand || true
```

... to ignore the return code...?

e.g.
pass each host as a string to `xargs` (one string at a time, using the xargs `-n1` flag, and the xargs `-I` flag, where `_` is the substitued value in this example.

e.g.

```
>echo google.com blahblah123.com | xargs -n1 -I_ host -l _   || true
;; Connection to 192.168.0.1#53(192.168.0.1) for google.com failed: connection refused.
;; Connection to 192.168.0.1#53(192.168.0.1) for blahblah123.com failed: connection refused.
```